# Algorithm for converting Latitude and Longitude to World Coordinates (OpenGL)

Tags: algorithm, opengl, latitude-longitude

I have a set of latitude and longitude co-ordinates which are to be rendered in a GL program I'm working on. I have information such as the number of units per latitude and longitude degree (I have the co-ordinates in decimal degrees, eg, 27.1234) - for example, 15 units per longitude, and 10 units per latitude. However, I've had problems with rendering.

This calculation gives me locations I can use for rendering, but it's not perfect. I initially tested only with co-ordinates such as S026.33.01.806 E148.46.27.009, and when I switched to co-ordinates such as N039.52.19.030 W075.14.28.107 the rendering ended up upside-down and horizontally flipped.

It may be a fundamental lack of understanding of OpenGL and how it interprets co-ordinates, or perhaps I'm approaching the problem the wrong way. I'm using Python and PyOpenGL, but I presume this algorithm is something that can be done without a specific language requirement.

EDIT: I have uploaded the code that seems to be most relevant to http://slexy.org/view/s21LKiD9tj.

Comment: It would be easier to spot the mistake in your code if you posted it.

Comment: There are various issues I can see.  First, although 1 degree of latitude is, to a first (spherical) approximation, the same distance regardless of position on the globe, 1 degree of latitude has a variable size, being largest at the equator and minuscule at the poles.  Second, I'm not sure if the World Coordinates you refer to are an OpenGL item or your description of how you interpret the position.  If you are looking at generating 3D cartesian coordinates, I can see various ways in which the display could be rendered upside down and flipped.  What happens with S026.33.01.806 W075.14.28.107?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: The co-ordinates are for a small area, and the units per degree of latitude and longitude are provided from the data source. By world co-ordinates I mean in the GL world (I come from a DirectX dev background, in case that helps. "World co-ordinates" are, in this case, effectively 3D cartesian co-ordinates with a z of zero). A little bit of inaccuracy is okay in this software. As for your provided example: the rendered items are flipped horizontally.

Comment: @meriton: which code specifically? I have an awful lot of code and I'd like to reduce the amount I provide instead of just dumping the entire thing.

Comment: @Matthew: what is the (3D position) of the viewpoint you are looking from?  Which direction are you looking at?  Since you are experiencing odd effects when the position changes from negative to positive (or vice versa) in both N-S and E-W directions, it may be that you are using absolute values when you should be allowing for signed values.

Comment: The view is orthographic with the camera looking straight down at the co-ordinates. The camera is positioned with an initial latitude and longitude in the same way every item is rendered with a latitude and longitude.

Comment: "What code specifically": The code that parses latitude/longitude, and the code that computes the world coordinates from those.

Comment: I have edited the original post with a link to code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Erm, the number of units for longitude is not constant? What strange kind of conversion function are you using?

Assuming the earth to be spherical with radius r, centered in the root of the coordinate system, with z-axis pointing north, x-axis pointing towards longitude 0, and y-axis pointing towards longitude 90, you can get cartesian coordinates as follows:

```
x = r * cos(latitude) * cos(longitude);
y = r * cos(latitude) * sin(longitude);
z = r * sin(latitude);
```

Note: If your language's trigonometric functions expect the arguments to be specified in radians rather than degrees, be sure to convert them first.

Comment: You can rotate the resulting world East or West with those equations, but you need to add this equation to the end of it to rotate North or South: Z = (Y * sin(Rotate)) + (Z * cos(Rotate)). This is the z line from a multiply vector by matrix.